# Handling IE8 Information Bar in SilkTest

Tags: java, internet-explorer-8, silktest

I'm automating a file download with SilkTest. In IE8, an information bar shows up saying "To help protect your security, Internet Explorer blocked... Click here for options...". I want to be able to target this with SilkTest. Is this possible? Is it a DOM element?

Disabling that security feature is not an option, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The security information bars are not DOM elements as far as I know. If you have a more recent version of Silk Test, you might be able to use the Accessibility support to dismiss the information bar.

**Note:** I work for Borland as part of the Silk Test team, so any opinions expressed in that regards are strongly biased.